# akka-cluster: Which remote actor is executing the job

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

As I understand with akka-cluster, frontend node receives the request and sends the job to one of the backend nodes for executing it. I want to find out for debugging purpose how to know which of the backend node is executing the job?

Does akka also provides some UI where one can look for current job executions happening on different backends?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in Akka Cluster that is specifically about work scheduling or frontend and backend nodes, that would just be one application out of many that you can possibly build on top of Akka Cluster and as such, if you would want an UI of some kind you would build that as well for your application.